adjustText for Categorical Y axis plots
I have a data set and i use adjustText to add column label to each line but as you can see the last line on the bottom shows label very close to its line
what can i do to make all lines and label to look like top line?


this is my code and dataset:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from adjustText import adjust_text

df = pd.DataFrame([['Trip: 450121805 - Batched_with: 450115425',
  '2024-01-17 12:22:52.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:27:51.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:47:14.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:47:46.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:47:14.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:59:26.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:59:26.000'],
 ['Trip: 450115425 - Batched_with: 450121805',
  '2024-01-17 11:57:32.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:02:31.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:14:53.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:15:25.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:47:14.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:48:54.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:59:26.000'],
 ['Trip: 450115515 - Batched_with: 450121805',
  '2024-01-17 11:57:58.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:02:58.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:15:10.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:15:41.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:47:14.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:49:06.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:59:26.000'],
 ['Trip: 450121805 - Batched_with: 450118017',
  '2024-01-17 12:22:52.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:27:51.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:47:14.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:47:46.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:47:15.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:59:26.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:59:26.000'],
 ['Trip: 450118017 - Batched_with: 450121805',
  '2024-01-17 12:08:52.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:13:51.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:28:09.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:28:52.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:47:15.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:52:29.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:59:26.000'],
 ['Trip: 450119629 - Batched_with: 450121805',
  '2024-01-17 12:15:07.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:20:07.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:38:06.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:38:26.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:47:15.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:55:45.000',
  '2024-01-17 12:59:26.000']])
df.set_index(0, inplace=True)
df.columns = ['created_in_time_1', 'created_in_time_2', 'created_in_time_3', 'created_in_time_4', 'created_in_time_5', 'created_in_time_6', 'created_in_time_7']

and
times_ = ['created_in_time_1', 'created_in_time_2', 'created_in_time_3', 'created_in_time_4', 'created_in_time_5', 'created_in_time_6', 'created_in_time_7']
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30, 15), sharex = True, sharey = True)
for t in times_:
    df[t] = pd.to_datetime(df[t])
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    ax.plot([row['created_in_time_1'], row['created_in_time_2'],
             row['created_in_time_3'], row['created_in_time_4'],
             row['created_in_time_5'], row['created_in_time_6'], row['created_in_time_7']],
            [i, i, i, i, i, i, i],
             '-X',
            label=i,
            linewidth=2.0)
    texts = [ax.text(row[j], i, '%s' %times_[n], ha='center', va='center') for n, j in enumerate(times_)]
    adjust_text(texts, expand=(5, 5),
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->', color='red'))

I tried almost every argument in adjustText function

I figure it out:
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30, 15), sharex = True, sharey = True)
texts = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    ax.plot([row['created_in_time_1'], row['created_in_time_2'],
             row['created_in_time_3'], row['created_in_time_4'],
             row['created_in_time_5'], row['created_in_time_6'], row['created_in_time_7']],
            [i, i, i, i, i, i, i],
             '-X',
            label=i,
            linewidth=2.0)
    for t in times_:
        texts.append(ax.text(row[t], i, t, ha='center', va='bottom'))
adjust_text(texts, expand=(2, 3), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->', color='red'))

